# Java 1.6 and Oracle JDBC 14 setQueryTimeout not working

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

We run Java 1.6 and use the latest ojdbc14.jar. We connect to a remote Oracle db.
We want to setQueryTimeout as the query must not take longer than 2 minutes to complete.

I have done this:

```
  statement = conn.prepareCall(call);
  statement.setQueryTimeout(120);
  statement.executeQuery();
```

After like 8 minutes it eventually times out! Any ideas or workaround for this?
As always your help is much appreciated!

Edit: We use thin driver

Comment: Why aren't you using ojdbc6.jar if you are using Java SE 6?

Comment: AFAIK support for `setQueryTimeout` is limited or non-existent in most drivers. Make sure the Oracle driver actually supports it.

Comment: Okay I will download the ojdbc6.jar and try with that, thanks...

Comment: No luck, still doesn't time out. I will have to find a jar that supports setQueryTimeout :|

Comment: Your driver version is stone age! Use 11.2.0.3.0. This works well with the timeout.

Answer (score 2):

See how query timeout works in Oracle JDBC driver here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=550257

Long story short:

1. It takes a full round trip to the database to cancel the SQL execution when the timeout expires. The database will get around to processing the cancel request when it feels like it.
2. The driver timeout mechanism is not a high precision mechanism. Since actually canceling the execution requires talking to the database over the network, there is no point in making the driver super precise. Even if the driver were precise, the network delays and time required for the database to respond to the cancel request would negate the precision of the driver. So the timeout is the MINIMUM amount of time the driver will give the SQL to execute before sending a cancel to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing -Doracle.net.disableOob=true in the client JVM system properties.  Per the [property documentation](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_DISABLE_OUT_OF_BAND_BREAK),

> Thin uses out of band breaks by default from 11g onwards. If the user prefers to use Inband breaks instead of Out of Band ones then this property could be set to true.

In some cases, either the underlying protocol does not support out of band breaks, or the database is not configured to listen for out of band breaks.