# Mybatis query timeout is not working with springboot, oracle driver

Tags: oracle, mybatis

I tried timeout for select query, but itseems its not working, below is the query which i gave in mapper.xml file., plz try to help me out.,

> " < select id="test" resultMap="testMap" timeout="20" >"

im using, oracle 8 driver 12.0.0.1, mybatis version 3.5, springboot

Comment: If your client is on Windows, you may have to set the system property `-Doracle.net.disableOob=true`. Both answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13645464/1261766) may be informative.

Comment: @ave, Thanks for the answer, i tried with this, it worked for count query, but for normal select query, timeout is not happening., any idea

Comment: From MyBatis point of view, there is no difference between select and count query (by 'count', I assumed that you mean `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`). If you could show us the exact steps to reproduce the issue on our end, we might be able to help. I usually recommend creating a small demo project  like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) for reliable reproduction. BTW, if the selected row(s) are locked, it may behave differently. See this [thread](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4107198/).

Comment: @ave, Thanks for the response, it seems rows are locked, but not sure, it behaves like this only., any way i tried with mybatis interceptor "StatementHandler" and canceled the query statement and closed the particular statement connection., could able to achieve this., but as of now will not use this, will try to optimize long running query in db level indexing or any other possible solution., thanks for the response., it was informative.,